# When I run my code into the Repl.it software, it doesn't recognize any of my variables whatsoever

Tags: javascript, string, function, loops, variables

I think my code is ok, but every time I get an unexpected token error. I am writing in Javascript (I am also brand new to it). I really need some help and it would be greatly appreciated :)
A snippet of the code:

```
function isitSublimeString(theString)
  var listaAlpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'        
        let lista = sorted(list(theString.toLowerCase()))
        let count = [1]
        let word = 0
        if (lista[0] != 'a');
              {return False}
        var i;
```

Comment: You are missing brackets around the function body `{}`

Comment: Also, you have `;` after the `if` so the condition is ignored and the next line runs every time.

Comment: Oh, and in JavaScript the boolean value is `false` with lowercase `f`

Answer (score 1):

Functions need curly braces:

```
function isitSublimeString(theString)**{**
  var listaAlpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'        
        let lista = sorted(list(theString.toLowerCase()))
        let count = [1]
        let word = 0
        if (lista[0] != 'a');
              {return False}
        var i;

**}**
```